# Using Public/Private Keys that were created with Putty

Tags: key, private, putty, ssh.net

I am following one the examples from a search of ssh.net examples.
This example uses public/private keys.
I have a general understanding, however the example has a .pem extension on the private key file. Mine is ppk
When I run the code it get the error Invalid private key file.
I can use this same key with putty and am able to logon with no issues.

Is there something I need to change to support the same key putty uses?

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

you have to convert the ppk to pem using puttygen.

Comment: Please do not answer duplicate question. Vote them to be closed as duplicate instead.